# Is this trig equation solvable without calculus?

Tags: trigonometry

Can I solve
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin^2(\mu)}{\sin^2(b)}d^2-1=R\cos\left(\frac{360l}{2\pi R}\right)$$
to get the ratio $d/R$ defined by some function of $\mu,b,l$ given that $\mu,b$ and $l$ are known values, but without using calculus.

I have edited the question sice i wasnt clear the first time

Comment: Just rearrange and simplify?!

Comment: Yes, what's the problem with samjoe's suggestion? Show how you solved it (effort), and where you got stuck (and must use calculus???).

Comment: I don't see how solving for $d$ algebraically poses any problem. This is just an equation like $x^2=2$.

Comment: @Allawonder my issue is getting the R out of the cosine function since I want the solution in the edited form above

Comment: Oh, you mean you want to solve for $R$? Because as you phrased your question it seems like you want to solve for $d$.

Comment: Oh, it seems you want $d$ to vary linearly with $R$. But the nature of the problem doesn't allow you to do that, unless you change the problem, or are content with an approximation.

Comment: @Allawonder yeah I can see that the question is very badly phrased I will rewrite it, essentially this question stems from the measurement of the moons distance $d$ in earth radii $R$ so I want the ratio $d/R$ in terms of $l,\mu,b$

Comment: If it's the ratio you need edit your question to ask that directly. You'll get better help that way. And again, you will have to be satisfied with an approximation. And one will have to use calculus.

Answer (score 0):

note that $$\frac{\sin^2(\mu)}{2\sin^2(b)}d^2=RC\cos\left(\frac{360l}{2\pi R}\right)+1$$ so
$$d^2=\frac{2\sin^2(b)}{\sin^2(\mu)}\left(RC\cos\left(\frac{360l}{2\pi R}\right)+1\right)$$
and $$d=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2\sin^2(b)}{\sin^2(\mu)}\left(RC\cos\left(\frac{360l}{2\pi R}\right)+1\right)}$$